# When saying "thanks" is an exaggeration

Tags: spoken-english

Once I visited one of my *English-speaking* friends' village. And my friend was *showing me round their garden.* Suddenly I asked him:

> **What is this flower called?**

He said:

> It's called **ABC.**

Then, I was silent, I had no idea as to what to say -- should I have said:

> **okay, thanks or something else.**

just to express I got what he said.

How would a **native English speaker** have replied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's ABC flower?

Comment: I would not like to mention the name so I used ABC.

Comment: Your response is fine. There is no set expression in these circumstances. Others might be **that's interesting, indeed, I'll remember that, it's really pretty** and so on.

Comment: I see. I thought your friend was joking.

Comment: @RonaldSole would native speakers use any conjunctions here?

Comment: @user100323 "I would not like to mention the name" - Why not? Is it obscene?

Comment: You could say what @kevin012 said: *I see* or something complimentary such as *that's lovely.*